# How to get dynamic Javascript-Code for different ElementId to change element.value with range-slider.value

Tags: javascript, html

I created dynamically a HTML-Form and changed the value in Form-Elements with Javascript. How can I also create the Javascript code dynamic? Or is there a better way to code in Javascript that every range and input element I create depend upon each other?

I thought about changing elements by classes but it doesn't works (maybe wrong coded?). And I was not sure if it works, because I have more than one Volume-input element (and pressure element).  They will be created for different objects in the CMS. I 'display: block/none;' them.

HTML-Code would look Like:

```
<form>
<label for="(dynamicID)">Volume</label>
<input type="number" class="text-center" id="(dynamicID)">
<input id="slide-(dynamicID)" type="range" class="slider" min="1" max="10" step="1"/>
</form>
```

Javascript to change the Value of the Input element when slider's input change (and also the other way round) looks Like:

```
var sliders = document.getElementById("slide-(dynamicID)");
var outputs = document.getElementById("(dynamicID)");
outputs.value = sliders.value;
sliders.oninput = function() {
 outputs.value = this.value;
}
outputs.oninput = function() {
  sliders.value = this.value;
}
```

That works Perfectly when I code it statically. I can code the HTML-Elements with my CMS dynamic.

I also will take any other advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sorry but i don't understand what do you actually want to achieve. can you update your question with the result you want to achieve so i can provide a way for doing that.

Comment: How you are placing the dynamic inputs and ranges? don't show us the static code show us the dynamic code then we can help

Comment: I create the dynamic code withmy CMS-extension Typo3-flux. By adding id="slide-{elementLabel}".

Comment: What about adding <script>JavaScript-Code</Script> also in html and change it with also the CMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function setValue(e){
  let sliders = document.getElementsByClassName("dynamicInput");
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(sliders,(slider)=>{
      slider.value = e.target.value
  })
}
let sliders = document.getElementsByClassName("dynamicInput");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(sliders,(slider)=>{
    slider.oninput = setValue;    
});
```

```html
<form>
<label for="(dynamicID)">Volume</label>
<input type="number" class="text-center dynamicInput" id="(dynamicID)">
<input id="slide-(dynamicID)" type="range" class="slider dynamicInput" min="1" max="10" step="1"/>
</form>
```

this is a bit mroe dynamic it works for all elements that have "dynamicInput" in the className and implment a .value setter